# Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN undefined (ldapjs)

Tags: express, dns, ldapjs

So, i tried to deploy my Express.Js app to my vps, but I get some error that refined to Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN undefined. The weird part is, it is doing just fine if I run this app on my localhost. Any body knows how to resolve this issue?

Here are the error log that I get.

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN undefined
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at Backoff.<anonymous> (/home/user/deploy-folder/app-api/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1228:12)
    at Backoff.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Backoff.backoff (/home/user/deploy-folder/app-api/node_modules/ldapjs/node_modules/backoff/lib/backoff.js:41:14)
    at /home/user/deploy-folder/app-api/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1214:15
    at f (/home/user/deploy-folder/app-api/node_modules/ldapjs/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at Socket.onResult (/home/user/deploy-folder/app-api/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1016:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) {
  errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by now you discovered the error, but in this particular case it seems that the variable you are using to setup ldap is not stated or resolves to `undefined`.

The proper way to do it according to the [documentation](http://ldapjs.org/client.html) is this:

```js
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389'
});
```